# Change value through pointer

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

We have a program which looks like this:

```
int TEST = 7;
// Put code here

*((int*) (p + 8)) |= 0x3f;
// TEST should be now 0x3f
```

You can see that variable p is undeclared. My question is what should variable p be so that TEST would be 0x3f?

I already tried this:

```
int *p = &TEST;
```

You can change the value of TEST now with pointer p but it doesn't seem to work with `*((int*) (p + 8)) |= 0x3f;`

Comment: what the hell is `*((int*) (p + 8)) |= 0x3f;`

Comment: @GradyPlayer A statement I guess?

Comment: smells like a school assignment

Comment: @GradyPlayer `8` is added to `p`, the result is converted to type "pointer to int", and the pointed-to value is bitwise-OR'd with `0x3F`.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic of pointer + integer can only be done in an array object otherwise it is invalid. So to answer your question, the answer is: nowhere. You cannot declare a `p` pointer with a value so `*((int*) (p + 8)) |= 0x3f;` will modify your `TEST` object in a portable way.

> (C99, 6.5.6p8) "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @FUZxxl well the title is *Change value through pointer* so my question addresses the fact that `p` cannot be a pointer.

Comment: The question title does not imply that `p` must be a pointer. If you cast something to a pointer, you get a pointer and with my answer a value is changed through a pointer even though `p` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is this:

```
uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)&TEST - 8;
```

Notice that `p` is not a pointer here, making `p` a pointer would rely on implementation defined or undefined behaviour (depending on how you do it) and is not a viable way to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: i think you mean &TEST

Comment: You might want p=&TEST-8, but it is still undefined behavior

Comment: and p is a pointer. its declared as one and loaded with an address

Comment: @Eugene How so? Please observe that I convert `&TEST` to `uintptr_t` to circumvent the undefined behaviour.

Comment: @pm100 OP doesn't say how `p` should be declared, in fact he asks how to do that. The only place where `p` is declared a pointer is in his attempt but his wording does not state that `p` must be a pointer.

Comment: @Eugene That applies when you operate on pointers, but I operate on an `uintptr_t` and as unsigned overflow is well-defined, `(int*)((uintptr_t)&TEST - 8 + 8)` is exactly equal to `&TEST`.

Comment: @Eugene Also, a pointer must survive a round-trip through `uintptr_t` (ISO 9899:2011 §7.20.1.4) and as the result compares equal to the original pointer, it points to the same object. Please again point out my undefined behaviour, I don't do any pointer arithmetic at all in my answer so §6.5.6 ¶8 doesn't apply.

Comment: @FUZxxt: you convinced me. I have removed the downvote.

Comment: @pm100 What's confusing? I'm declaring `p` to *not* be a pointer and then I specifically explain that `p` is *not* a pointer to make sure that this is not seen as an accident. If `p` had to be a pointer, this question would not have an answer.

Comment: @M.M Yeah, that's kinda frustrating. They all think I'm doing undefined pointer arithmetic when I'm casting to `uintptr_t` specifically to evade that problem. It's like they can't read.

Answer (score 0):

@kkmah7 - I'm wondering the same thing as Grady Player: "What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `*((int*) (p + 8)) |= 0x3f`?"

More specifically, I'm wondering about "(p + 8)".  Are you trying to modify the offset (change where p points to), or the value (are you trying to add "8" to "TEST").  If the latter, then "(p + 8") is wrong.  If the former, then it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This example might help clarify:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int value = 2;
  int *p = &value;

  *p += 2;
  printf ("value= %d, *p= %d\n", value, *p);
  /* Output: value= 4, *p= 4 */

  *p |= 0x3f;
  printf ("value= %d, *p= %d\n", value, *p);
  /* Output: value= 63, *p= 63 */

  return 0;
}
```